# AudioPolicyManagerBase error

Tags: android

My LogCat contains the following line multiple times:

08-01 09:15:03.101: ERROR/AudioPolicyManagerBase(95): unknown stream type

Is this an actual error in my app or something to ignore?

Comment: Code.. you should put your code

Comment: +1 on the code.  Quadroid, did you ever figure this out?  I have a streaming radio app and have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using AndEngine or any 2d-3d engine? If so, there's the answer. They usually internally set the audio stream as STREAM_MUSIC.

If you are using a Media object, are you releasing it? 
Are you streaming any audio extension that the standard Android music player cannot play?

Anyway put some code and tell us what your application is intended to do so we can provide a better answer :)

Comment: Looks like my device is logging these errors even when my application is not running. So it must be something other than my application causing this.

Comment: Probably your launcher is running some 2d-3d built-in engine, thus causing the error. Don't worry about it then.